# Upload to iTunesConnect failing

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I am getting this error and warning for all the frameworks i have used in my project when i try to upload the archive on Itunes connect.

ERROR ITMS-90635: "Invalid Mach-O Format. The Mach-O in bundle "XXXX!.app/Frameworks/BRYXBanner.framework" isn’t consistent with the Mach-O in the main bundle. The main bundle Mach-O contains armv7(machine code) and arm64(machine code), while the nested bundle Mach-O contains armv7(bitcode) and arm64(bitcode). Verify that all of the targets for a platform have a consistent value for the ENABLE_BITCODE build setting."
WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/XXXX!.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."

WARNING ITMS-90080: "The executable 'Payload/XXXX!.app/Frameworks/Bolts.framework' is not a Position Independent Executable. Please ensure that your build settings are configured to create PIE executables. For more information refer to Technical Q&A QA1788 - Building a Position Independent Executable in the iOS Developer Library."

I think it is an itunes problem since i reverted the code to an older version on github which i had already uploaded and tried but Again while uploading the Archive I am getting the same error for all frameworks.

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Try turning off bitcode in build options.

Comment: It was off in settings but still didnt work..so i added this to pod file and it worked : post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end
end

Comment: can you elaborate pls @subodh1989

Comment: i was using cocaopods so in pod file I appended a few lines to force turn the ENABLE_BITCODE off..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was off in settings at both places but still didnt work..so i added this to pod file and it worked :

```
post_install do |installer| 
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target| 
    target.build_configurations.each do |config| 
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO' 
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: How do you add that pod file?

Comment: I am using cocoapods for including frameworks . to do pod installation for build dependencies ,check this out : https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Comment: Sorry I wrote wrong my question. I'm using cocoapods too but my question was about if that code needs to put it in some particular place of the `Podfile`, for example at the top or below .

Comment: i added it to the bottom before end.basically it should be b/w target and end.

Answer (score -4):

Rule number 1 of debugging: It's your problem. By saying "I think it's an iTunes problem" you shut your brain off from any chance of finding the solution. The way to solve problems when you have an error message is to read the error message and to try to understand it.

The message is really absolutely clear. There is an error and a warning. The error will be the real problem. Read the error message. Is there anything unclear about it? You have two bits of code with different setting for ENABLE_BITCODE. You need to change one of them. Look at the settings in your project and how ENABLE_BITCODE is set, then change it.

Comment: it indeed seems to be an iTunes Connect problem -- at least the `WARNING ITMS-90080`. Check this - https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5453 
 Also, this isn't just related to CocoaPods, the issue seems to be creeping up everywhere!